# Search all values within parenthesis by using Regex Python

Tags: python, regex, text

I have a list of text like this format-

**2021-07-11 18:34:24,381: Mouse clicked at (159, 88) with Button.left**

*Here, I want to search this "(159, 88)" pattern with the bracket from my entire text file.*

The 1st and 2nd values in the parenthesis can be One digit to four digits. I mean this format can be (1, 888) or (20, 32) or (134, 4) or (365, 567) or (1240, 122) or (1345, 1245).

Now, by using regex, how do I solve this problem?

My expected output is- **(384, 567)**

Please help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the pattern `'\(\d+,\s*\d+\)'` to match the substring you want.

```py
>>> import re
>>> text = '2021-07-11 18:34:24,381: Mouse clicked at (159, 88) with Button.left'
>>> re.findall('\(\d+,\s*\d+\)', text)
['(159, 88)']
```

Understanding the pattern: `'\(\d+,\s*\d+\)'`

```py
\(    : Look for opening parenthesis, \ is used as escape character

\d+   : Look for one or more digits

,     : Look for exactly one comma

\s*   : Zero or more white space characters

\d+   : Look for one or more digits again

\)    : Look for closing parenthesis, \ is used as escape character
```

Comment: Thank you so much. It works fine. Another help will be really appreciated.  I want to append this output in a text file, but I don't know how to append it with a new line. Can you help me with this?